# Error while trying to add docker support : Value cannot be null ... netCoreVersion

Tags: docker, visual-studio, .net-core

I had a very simple .Net Core console app that I was using to try experiment with docker/containers. I had heard that Visual Studio had great docker support and wanted to see if I could leverage it. After creating the .Net Core from the Visual Studio Templates, I right-clicked the Project to add "Docker Support...", then when prompted for Linux vs Windows, I selected Windows and then got the following error:

> An error occurred while adding Docker file support to this project.
>
> Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: netCoreVersion

I've tried various things and nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much troubleshooting, this is what solved my problem. The `TargetFramework` I was using was not being recognized by Visual Studio. I wanted to test using a Windows only build because that is my primary use case.

Right-clicking the Project Properties, the TargetFramework was `.NET 6.0` but the Target OS was `Windows` and NOT `(None)`.

Those 2 settings combine the csproj file to have a setting of

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

instead of

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

**The Fix**

Essentially get your *TargetFramework* to be `net6.0`. You can edit raw, or just select `(None)` as your Target OS. You can then add the Docker File, and then reset your project back to your Target OS.